# Calling an event handler defined in parent from child component in React

Tags: reactjs, components, parent-child, redux

In my redux/react application I have a parent component `SourceList` containing child items of type `SourceItem`. I decided (and not sure if that's really true to react/redux) to let the child control to be oblivious to what the click handler is and pass the click event handler from parent to child.

I'm still quite new to redux/react and the code is like following

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { actions } = this.props;
  if(this.props.side === 'right') { return; }
  actions.fetchSources(); // this works perfectly
}

handleChildClick(source) {
  const { actions } = this.props;
  if(this.props.side === 'right') { 
    actions.changeRight(source); 
    return; 
  }
  actions.changeLeft(source);
}

render() {
  const { actions } = this.props.actions;
  var that = this;
  var rightSide = this.props.side === 'right';
  var sources = this.props.sources.items.map(function(source) {
    return <SourceItem 
              key={source.id} 
              onClick={that.handleChildClick.bind(that, source)}
              source={source}/>;
    });
  return <ul>{sources}</ul>
}
```

`actions` is bound to action creators with `bindActionCreators`

And the child component just gets the values from `props`:

```
class SourceItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { onClick, selected, source } = this.props;
    return <li onClick={onClick}>{source.name}</li>
  }
}
```

While this works, I don't feel like keeping a reference to `this` in `that` and calling `bind` function as in `that.handleChildClick.bind(that, source)` is the right redux/react way.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Redux tutorial gives the example on exactly the same situation – http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can use the ES6 syntax for function and do `handleChildClick = (source) => { ... }` instead of `handleChildClick(source) { ... }`. With this the `this` will reference to the correct object and you won't need to do `that = this`. Just a side note.

Comment: @LaFaulx, I know about that tutorial, but the code there is different - the classes there are defined in different way and I was confused :)

Answer (score 2):

A good approach will be defining `handleChildClick` in the constructor function, this is to prevent the function from being recreated every time it is called via `onClick`. To also solve the issue with `this => that`, use the arrow function.

```
constructor([props]) {
  this.handleChildClick = this.handleChildClick.bind(this)
} 

....
render() {
  const { actions } = this.props.actions;
  var rightSide = this.props.side === 'right';
  var sources = this.props.sources.items.map((source) => {
    return <SourceItem 
          key={source.id} 
          onClick={this.handleChildClick}
          source={source}/>;
    });
  return <ul>{sources}</ul>
```

}

```
.....

class SourceItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { onClick, selected, source } = this.props;
    return <li onClick={onClick(source)}>{source.name}</li>
  }
}
```